# LoaderThrottle magic tricks

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, android-listfragment

I'm new in Android. I spend my free summertime on studying it to try to develop an application.

I need to display in a list (ListView), data from a database table, in order for the user to manipulate it.

I found simpleCursorAdapter but it is indicated as deprecated to avoid performing queries in UI Thread. 
With my fisrt table, which will keep small, it would perhaps not be a problem, but with main table it would. So I studied LoaderManager recommanded replacement.

I found LoaderThrottle example in ApiDemos SDK Samples to try to understand LoaderManager mechanisms. 
ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderThrottle.java

I tried hard to understand this example but I still have some points I don't understand.

I didn't found android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and android.R.id.text1 on line 406 :

```
            // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] { MainTable.COLUMN_NAME_DATA },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I also didn't find android.R.id.content on line 377:

```
        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
    if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        ThrottledLoaderListFragment list = new ThrottledLoaderListFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
    }
```

There is no simple_list_item_1.xml in ApiDemos layout directory. 
There is a lot of text1 in different layout but didn't find which one it could possibly be if any.
Found 3 "content", one in content_browser.xml of type ContentBrowserActivity$Content...

So I don't understand where is the link with a ListView I was expecting.

So for me it's still "magic" since I don't see the hidden links between ListView and the adapter.

What I am supposed to have in my ListView? 
Nothing? One TextView per data I get from my database?

If someone had an example of LoaderManager to link a database table with a ListView not melt with all other ApiDemos, I would enjoy it!

Thanks in advance for your hints and answers,
Florent

Comment: `simple_list_item_1.xml` and friends are "internal" public resources - i.e. ready-made list items / views & associated identifiers that can be used by applications _without_ bothering to make your own. They will typically also be styled according to the device default.

Comment: it's here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I now understand better the mechanism.
There is no need to create a particular layout.

So I think the link with the rest of the application is in FragmentTabs activity, line 54:

```
bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
    .setText("Throttle")
    .setTabListener(new TabListener<LoaderThrottle.ThrottledLoaderListFragment>(
            this, "throttle", LoaderThrottle.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class)));
```

ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.java

Best regards,
Florent